# Running mpirun over multiple nodes through WSL

Tags: mpi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openmpi, wsl-2

My first post on stackoverflow, kindly pardon articulation of the problem I am facing.

Goal: To run OpenFOAM simulation by combining the computing power of two windows PCs running WSL2 which are connected by LAN.

Constrains: Daily workflow dependent on windows ecosystem so can't switch to linux. OpenFOAM require [Linux](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/precompiled/windows) environment.

Software: Both PCs running Windows 10 with WSL2 on top of it. No firewall available between the two PCs.

I have set-up password-less SSH (custom port 2222) on both PCs (within WSL) and is connecting fine. But for it to work I had to use port-forwarding using the following command as described here [WSL Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking).

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=2222 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=2222 connectaddress=<WSL2 IP address>;
```

I have also setup NFS with PC1 being the server and PC2 being client. For it to work I had to forward port 443, and 2049 also. So in total three ports 2222, 443 and 2049 ports are forwarded on both PCs.

I have created a common folder on PC1 named "run" under /home/user/ with nobody:nogroup and permission set to 777. I have mounted the same folder on PC2 at the same location (/home/user/). Everything works fine and the files are in sync.

To test if mpirun is working, I copied the [mpi_hello.c](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Emmalensek/cs220/schedule/code/week07/mpi_hello.c.html) file to the folder on PC1, compiled it and run it using the following command.

```
mpicc mpi_hello.c -o mpi_hello
mpirun -np 4 ./mpi_hello
```

The output came as

```
Hello from PC1, rank 0 (of 4).
Hello from PC1, rank 1 (of 4).
Hello from PC1, rank 2 (of 4).
Hello from PC1, rank 3 (of 4).
```

Then I created a hostfile.txt file with the following data

```
PC1 slots=4
PC2 slots=4
```

Then ran the following command

```
mpirun -np 8 --hostfile hostfile.txt ./mpi_hello
```

which is not giving any output or throwing error. It just hangs and I need to press Ctrl+C to exit. When I comment out PC2 in hostfile.txt everything works fine.
Where am I going wrong?

Edit:
I checked which ports are being accessed by mpirun using the command `sudo netstat -plnt` and found that it uses some random ports from 15000 to 65000.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36767           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1016/rpc.mountd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54495           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1016/rpc.mountd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45607         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5085/mpirun
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38761           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59787           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5085/mpirun
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      520/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      965/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48563           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1016/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::44695                :::*                    LISTEN      1016/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::39231                :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::60333                :::*                    LISTEN      1016/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      520/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      965/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::34195                :::*                    LISTEN      1016/rpc.mountd
```

So I tried port forwarding all ports from 15000 to 65000 on both PCs and checked if mpirun is working, but it didn't work.

Comment: Though SSH is (generally) needed in order to start the MPI server/helper on the remote node, this is (generally) not the only TCP/IP socket required. For example, Open MPI needs extra socket pairs for OoB management (e.g. `mpirun` to `orted` aka MPI server) but also for `btl/tcp` (e.g. process to process communication). I do not understand why you need port forwarding (IIRC, from PC1, `ssh -p 2222 localhost` will end up on PC2) but that suggests there is something wrong with you r network connectivity (firewall? routing? virtual machines?)

Comment: Thank you @GillesGouaillardet for the reply. I need to enable port forwarding because WSL 2 has a virtualized ethernet adapter with its own unique IP address. I have tried it without port forwarding but both SSH and nfs didn't work. Then I referred the documentation by Microsoft and did the port forwarding. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan)
I also tried port forwarding all ports from 15000 to 65000 and checked if mpirun is working but it didn't work.

Comment: I checked which ports are being accessed by mpirun using the command `sudo netstat -plnt` and found that it uses some random ports from 15000 to 65000. So I tried port forwarding all ports from 15000 to 65000 on both PCs and checked if mpirun is working but still it didn't work.

Comment: That probably won't be enough ... One option would be to have WSL use a bridge network (not sure this is even possible/supported). Another option would be to setup a VPN between your WSL instances, and have MPI use it.

Comment: I believe WSL1 uses a bridged network. But I can't install nfs-server on WSL1 which is needed to ensure common directory is available on both WSL instances. I tried bridging WSL2 adaptor and local network adaptor but I lost network connectivity completely. I would like to know how to set-up a VPN between 2 WSL instances running on 2 separate PCs. Also would like to know what is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I think the root cause if Open MPI internally send the WSL IP, but this IP is unreachable from the other WSL (you need to use the host IP, and then port forwarding will do the trick; unfortunately, there is no way to tell MPI to substitute WSL IP with host IP). I am sure you can find plenty of OpenVPN tutorials to help you setup a VPN between your WSL

Comment: Thank you @GillesGouaillardet. I will try out the OpenVPN option. I also had a thought of keeping one WSL2 instance on PC1 just for nfs share and WSL1 instances on both PCs for mpirun. But I couldn't do that because I couldn't mount the nfs share using nfs-common and connect WSL1s using SSH. So I think only option left with me is using OpenVPN.